# Table schema for IP Address Lookups

Tags: mysql, database, geolocation, ip-address, lookup

I am working on a project in which we need to do `IP Address lookups`. So for this we have got the datasets and now the next steps is to populate this datasets in to the table. And then have some service setup that will accept `IP Address as an input` and then lookup the database basis on `IP Address`. So below is the dataset will look like-

```
ip_address      country region  city           metro-code   latitude    longitude   postal-code   country-code   region-code    city-code   continent-code  country-code

24.32.116.116   usa       tx    clarksville    623           33.6103    -95.0498    75426            840           44             34918            6            us
65.29.108.232   usa       mi    novi           505           42.4637    -83.4604    48375            840           23             4339             6            us
66.169.99.69    usa       tx    ft worth       623           32.7016    -97.3823    76109            840           44             771              6            us
72.70.100.111   usa       ma    peabody        506           42.5332    -70.9726    1960             840           22             1392             6            us
174.252.116.137 usa       va    oakton         511           38.8892    -77.3222    22124            840           47             3860             6            us
68.55.144.242   usa       md    pasadena       512           39.1276    -76.5125    21122            840           21             4358             6            us
174.252.83.27   usa       pa    lancaster      566           40.0459    -76.3542    17603            840           39             333              6            us
174.78.192.31   usa       ga    warner robins  503           32.5958    -83.6384    31088            840           11             5052             6            us
98.192.146.235  usa       fl    panama city    656           30.1804    -85.5598    32404            840           10             671              6            us
71.192.181.20   usa       ma    springfield    543           42.1187    -72.5483    1109             840           22             967              6            us
76.183.54.227   usa       tx    dallas         623           32.7202    -96.6769    75217            840           44             77               6            us
69.62.143.140   usa       ca    granite bay    862           38.7442    -121.191    95746            840           5              49451            6            us
69.142.76.32    usa       nj    penns grove    504           39.707     -75.4467    8069             840           31             2335             6            us
70.173.54.93    usa       nv    las vegas      839           36.2059    -115.225    89108            840           29             173              6            us
98.242.8.222    usa       ca    fresno         866           36.7968    -119.883    93722            840           5              19               6            us
```

**Problem Statement:-**

We are expecting traffic around `100 Millions calls` per day for the `IP Address lookup`.

And this dataset will be worldwide datasets meaning for all the countries. And we are planning to store these datasets in `MySql database` which is `In Memory Database` here.

Now my question is should I create only a `single table` with the above mentioned columns? Or should I normalize the above table into two or three? And do I need to create an index on any columns if any.?

Basically I am trying to know how should I setup the schema for this table so that lookup doesn't take that much time with the traffic we are going to expect. And our service which will be doing lookups should return the response very fast.

Comment: Aside from the number of calls (100 million per day? really?). How many IPs are you planning on storing? All 4+ billion? Because that's a bit of a challenge as well.

Comment: Yes that is the current traffic we have on our existing service. I don't know whether there will be 4 billion IP's or not. Because I am going to get this Geolocation Data Set from `one of the Geolocation Data Provider like Maxmind`. And when I ask them what will be the size of datasets. They said it would be around 40GB.

Comment: To directly answer your question you would definitely need indexes. But a single table or multiple I don't think MySQL would be a good solution for this either way in terms of performance

Comment: I see. Then what database I should take a look into?

Comment: I agree with the answer @Recurse posted

Answer (score 0):

Based on your numbers I would say you are looking at 3-5k/s peak, over 40GB. Assuming the query you are interested in is IP->record, I recommend against running directly against mysql.

Were I designing your system, I would be planning on:

1. A documented-oriented store to store/serve the raw data from your data provider. One of Tokyo-cabinet, Cassandra, or HBase, would do fine here.
2. A fully normalised (probably star-schema) mysql instance to canonicalise the data for QA purposes.
3. A memcached or similar distributed in-memory record-cache to serve the data via a light-weight web-server shim.

The post-QA data can be either served to the cache direct from mysql or from 'clean' attributes stored in the doc-store. The latter is probably preferable unless you are likely to need to perform regular ad hoc correlated queries against the store, in which case you might be better off dedicating the time and server resources to mysql.

Frankly, you do not want to be performing a database query per transaction.